# Why laravel api.php routes give a 404 error?

Tags: 18.04, php7, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.8.24 in Ubuntu 18.04 And This is the first time I'm writing an API. I'll add a test code here.

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::get('/api',function(){
    return "Test api";
});
```

When I go to `http://my_localhost_link/api` it gives a 404 error

Routes in `routes/web.php` are working fine.

Can please anybody tell me what did I miss or what went wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to run: php atrisan key:generate
Also I'd like to see your config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `route/api.php`, you need to add `/api/` prefix to your `uri`.

for example:

```
Route::get('/api',function(){
    return "Test api";
});
```

you need to call `http://my_localhost_link/api/someroute`.

Answer (score 6):

This can be resolved from apache, if you enable mod_rewrite option. So you need to run

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Changes in the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This is a real solution. Thank you!

Comment: This solved for me

Comment: Still getting 404 :/

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `php artisan serve --port 8000` command ? Default middleware of serve is /api. Your url also /api. Run command and the open [http://localhost:8000/api/api](https://localhost:8000/api/api)

Answer (score 0):

laravel api routes difficulty have *api* prefix you can change/remove it on *app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php*

```
   $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api') <-HERE
            ->middleware('api') 
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

also you can run

```
php artisan route:list
```